# Raspberry PI 2 HDMI to coaxial?

Tags: hdmi, television-tuner

I have a Raspberry pi 2 that only has HDMI display port.

I need to feed the RPi display to 4 TV's in the office (one RPi drive 4 TV's)

I have coaxial cables connected to the TV's and they all connected to a one-to-four coaxial splitter.

Is there a way to convert the RPi's HDMI to coaxial to feed it into the splitter?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of coaxial? or you means video cable with separate audio, video plugs (typically, red, white, and yellow)?

Comment: **COAX** typically refers to the Antenna/Cable style connector with screw on terminal and single conductor with braided shield, RCA refers to color coded connectors typical for video connections.  COAX usually carries RF based video format  similar to analog TV Stations. Its commonly used in CCTV systems where it runs on "one channel" (e.g. channel 3). The video output chip on RPI can produce "composite" video no problem (single , usually yellow, RCA Connector) , but not RF without a converter. The best option is to use an HDMI to RF converter, of which there are many on the market.

Answer (score 1):

The RPI 2 has an headphone jack, and it happens to also output video.

Something from Amazon to do what you need:

- RCA Compact RF Modulator (CRF907A)
- Zune A/V Output Cable

Connect the AV output cable to the RPI, and connect the components to the RCA Compact RF Modulator, then you connect your Modulator to your coax runs as needed.  Then on the TVs, select channel 3 or 4.